# Failing to collect dependencies maven

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to download files of versions within range start.version and end.version in parent pom.
And, choosing specific version in child pom.

Parent POM

```
<properties>
<start.version>1.1.0</start.version>
<end.version>2.1.0</end.version>
</properties>

 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>release</id>
        <properties>
        <model.version>[${start.version},${end.version}) </model.version> 
        </properties>
    </profile>
    </profiles>
```

**EDIT: In parent POM I have also added model dependency**

```
<dependencies>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sample.project</groupId> 
    <artifactId>model</artifactId> 
    <version>${model.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Child POM

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sample.project</groupId> 
<artifactId>model</artifactId> 
<version>${model.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

All versions within range are downloaded but failing to collect dependencies.
When pass these arguments in goals **-Dstart.version=1.1.0 -Dend.version=2.1.0**. It is working fine.

But, not collecting when I give in properties.
I tried adding plugins in parent POM

```
    <argLine>${start.version}<argLine>

    <compilerArgs>
      <arg>${start.version}</arg>
      <arg>${end.version}</arg>
    </compilerArgs>
```

And, copied these in CHILD POM. But, not working.

Comment: I don't know about this, but is tag `model.version` right? is open with `[` and close with `)`

Comment: Why using version ranges? And why using that in compiler args?

Comment: Yes. Above one is right. While giving [{model.version}) like this, gives error "Only fullly-qualified sets allowed in multiple set scenario"

Comment: Hi khmarbaise, It's because I will be selecting specific range in different child POM's. I tried using compiler args in parent to pass value to child POM(Because, properties not working). Working when I pass value in Goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to give dependency inside dependency management in Parent.

```
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sample.project</groupId> 
    <artifactId>model</artifactId> 
    <version>${model.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

By giving so, child POM Built successfully.
Can anyone explain pls!